# cannot run ruby with aptana studio 3 on windows 7

Tags: ruby, interpreter, aptana3

i'm new to ruby and am trying to get it to run on windows 7 using aptana studio 3. however, i an unable to run .rb programs due to 'lack of interpreter' as aptana is unable to find a ruby executable. i saved my program with .rb extension and looked for ways i could set a path to the ruby interpreter. there is no option to set up an interpreter for ruby in aptana preferences. am i missing something here?
i searched the web, but all i found was that the exact problem happened to people in linux. although it was solved, it was sovled in terms of linux and a windows user like me couldn't quite understand how the problem was fixed.
another search gave me a bit of info that aptana had changed and was no longer offering the same interpreter management environment as it did in previous versions:

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1591-cant-choose-ruby-interpreter-in-ubuntuaptana-studio-3-beta

so i'm really stuck here. i really want to work with aptana since it's much easy on the eyes with it's dark theme. eclipse, not so. overall i'd really like to run ruby on aptana.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 7/Aptana Studio 3/Ruby 1.9.3.

One solution that worked for me was to run RubyInstaller as administrator.   If you do not do this, the PATH environment variable does not get set, and the Aptana toolset does not seem to find ruby.

(This is using the RubyInstaller from http://rubyinstaller.org/.)

I guess that it might be possible just to set the PATH environment variable to point to the correct ruby binary, but I did not try this.